# Facebook Photo Posting App Doesn't Work?

Tags: php, facebook, photo

I used a Facebook Developers script called "Upload photos to a User's profile" (check it out : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto) but it doesn't work...

Here's my code :

```
<?php
  // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('facebook/src/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'I_ENTERED_MY_APP_ID_HERE',
    'secret' => 'I_ENTERED_MY_APP_SECRET_HERE',
    'fileUpload' => true,
    'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

  $photo = '/pictures/1.jpg'; // Path to the photo on the local filesystem
  $message = 'Look at this picture I just uploaded !';
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        // Upload to a user's profile. The photo will be in the
        // first album in the profile. You can also upload to
        // a specific album by using /ALBUM_ID as the path 
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos/', 'POST', array(
                                         'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                         'message' => $message,
                                         )
                                      );
        echo '<pre>Photo ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
        echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'photo_upload'
                       )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      // To upload a photo to a user's wall, we need photo_upload  permission
      // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
      // need to specify it here.
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload') );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I refresh my website page, it doesn't upload the image in my database to my wall... Can anyone tell me what's the problem..?

Comment: any errors? `error_log($e->getMessage());` would log the error!

Comment: Thanks for answer. It tells me : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getMessage() on a non-object in /home/u629000819/public_html/default.php on line 63`